# source of proof for a characterization of normal distribution

Tags: probability, reference-request, statistics

I want to know the proof of the following statement about normal distribution:

If the sample mean and sample variance are independent for a population, then the distribution of the population is normal.

I cannot find the proof in any probability/statistics textbook that I have. Please help.

Comment: Where did you see the _assertion_ that this is true?  Did the assertion say the population is normal if this is true of _all_ sample sizes?

Comment: @Michael Hardy: Yes, I think independence is true for all sample sizes in order to get the assertion. I forgot where I see this assertion.

Answer (score 1):

See [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4354/distributions-other-than-the-normal-where-mean-and-variance-are-independent) question on Stats.SE

There are articles quoted here but no proofs shown.  Wikipedia also quotes an article.

So far I haven't found the proof

Comment: I see. Not sure if any textbook contains the proof, besides the two papers referenced therein.